# Getting System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException when trying to set a property using ExpressionEvaluator library

Tags: c#

I made a sandbox example that generates the exception:

```
public class Account
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

[Fact]
public void MyTest()
{
    dynamic scope = new ExpandoObject();
    scope.Account = new Account();
    scope.Account.Status = "test0";

    // Can we get the value of the property?
    var result = new CompiledExpression("Account.Status").ScopeCompile().DynamicInvoke((object)scope);
    Assert.Same("test0", result); // Yes we can!

    // Can we set the value of the property?
    new CompiledExpression("Account.Status = 'test1'").ScopeCompile().DynamicInvoke((object)scope); // This throws an exception
    Assert.Same("test1", ((string)(scope.Account.Status)));
}
```

If it's not clear I have a scope `ExpandoObject` that has properties that are not dynamic - and I'm trying to set a property (`Status`) of a property (`Account`) through parsing an expression.  **What am I doing wrong/why am I getting an exception setting when getting works fine?**

I'm using this library:

https://csharpeval.codeplex.com/

`> Install-Package ExpressionEvaluator`

Alternatively, if there's a better library to do this (I've already given up on Simpro) then let me know and I can use it, instead.

(I'm using xunit as my tester, but I don't think that matters - hence `[Fact]` and not MsTest attributes.)

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation for CompiledExpression](https://csharpeval.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Usage&referringTitle=Documentation) you need to use single quotes for string literals. So, the setter should be:

```
new CompiledExpression("Account.Status = 'test1'").ScopeCompile()
    .DynamicInvoke((object)scope);
```

EDIT:

I've got this working:

```
var exp = new CompiledExpression("Status = 'test1'").ScopeCompile<Account>();
exp(scope.Account);
```

This also works:

```
var x = new CompiledExpression("Status = 'test2'").ScopeCompile<Account>();
var y = new CompiledExpression("Account").ScopeCompile();
x(y(scope));
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at it! Unfortunately the same exception is being thrown, even after making the change :/